# Fill null values from other column using Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

How can I fill in ? or null values in col2 with the corresponding values in col1 using Teradata SQL?

Data

```
col1    col2 
10       10   
11       ?
12       12
14       ?
65       ?
```

Expected Output

```
col1    col2 
10       10   
11       11
12       12
14       14
65       65
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `COALESCE`:

```sql
SELECT col1, COALESCE(col2, col1) AS col2
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY col1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.col1,
case
  when c.col2 is null then c.col1
  else col2
end as col2
from your_table as c
```